# Validating a Active Directory User

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory

To check for a user's existence in Active Directory, which one is the better .Net library to use?

```
System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider
```

or

```
System.DirectoryServices
```

I'm using using `System.DirectoryServices` and I feel it is the exact one to use. I do see there are similar features provided in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're on .NET 4.0, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // do something here....     
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: Yes, It is correct. My question is can I use System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider  for similar purpose?

Comment: @Nilaa: that is the ASP.NET membership provider - that needs to be configured separately and correctly, not sure if you could use it without all the setup and everything. I wouldn't use it - unless you're already using ASP.NET membership stuff anyway....